# Disable/Don't offer some drop locations on ng2-dragula

Tags: angular, dragula, ng2-dragula

I have some placeholder elements, which should not be used as drop location. Is there an option to disable some drop locations or to hide some drop locations? I [know](https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-dragula/#2-do-not-add-any-child-elements-that-arent-meant-to-be-draggable) that you shouldn't do this

> Do not add any child elements that aren't meant to be draggable

but isn't that, what [`accepts`](https://github.com/bevacqua/dragula#optionsaccepts) is for?

```
this.dragulaService.createGroup('cards', {
  accepts: (el, target, source, sibling) => {
    if (sibling !== null && sibling.classList.contains('invisible'))
      return false;

    return true;
  }
});
```

The issue is that `target`, and `source` are *containers*. I would need the new location as *target*, but the closest thing I've got is `sibling` (which is not what I want).

`drop` and `over` events also seem to take only *containers* into account.

Is there any solution for this?

**Update:**

[Here is my workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56459647/426227) for this problem.

Comment: Please create StackBlitz demo for this - I use very similar control with accepts and it is work, so you have an error in your implementation.

Comment: @kris_IV: I would have to create a separate MVCE, but I don't think `accepts` is the right one. Taken from the documentation: *You can set `accepts` to a method with the following signature: `(el, target, source, sibling)`. It'll be called to make sure that an element `el`, that came from container `source`, can be dropped on container `target` before a `sibling` element.* You only have container and sibling - this is not what I want. It should be dropped on any child div, if it hasn't the class `invisible`.